# Android check whether NFC enabled SIM card or normal SIM card

Tags: android, nfc

I am working with an Android Application. The application uses NFC technology and its main task if to do mobile payments.

My Question is, is there any way or any api where I can programatically check if the SIM card is built using NFC chip or not? I want to do a check in the application whether there is NFC enabled SIM card or normal SIM card.

Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't aware that SIM cards could have NFC chips. I am used to NFC radios being in the phone itself.

Comment: Yes, its possible and there are some applications using this technology.

Comment: @CommonsWare "NFC-enabled SIM card" typically means that the UICC/SIM card has a SWP interface so that it can be directly connected to a NFC controller chip on the mobile device. So the NFC-SIM would not (typically) have its own NFC radio.

Comment: @abhi did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Using OpenMobileAPI library, you can open the channel using AID of the applet installed in the UICC. If channel open is successful, it means it supports NFC-SWP.

Comment: Are you sure? I think the SWP-NFC is not involved into communication through OpenMobileAPI...